# Как можно получить id с этой ссылки?

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="/events/index/?id=2" target="_blank" class="bt" data-id="2">Смотреть</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите получить `id` именно из адреса ссылки, что лежит в `href` то могу предложить следующий вариант.

Можно разными способами получить элемент со страницы, в качестве примера я выбрал [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), далее взял нулевой элемент `[0]` так как у нас всего один элемент, а затем взял его `href`.

После этого взял [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) для получения индекса искомой подстроки и вывел подстроку через [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring). Вот сам код:

```js
function getId() {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName('bt')[0].href;
  alert(el.substr(el.indexOf("?id=") + 1)); // +4 даст только цифру 
}
```

```html
<a href="/events/index/?id=2" target="_blank" class="bt" data-id="2">Смотреть</a>
<br>
<button onclick="getId();">id</button>
```

Либо, если нужно значение из аттрибута `data-id`, то можем сделать так, через метод [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), который возвращает значение указанного атрибута элемента:

```js
function getId() {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName('bt')[0];
  alert(el.getAttribute('data-id'));
}
```

```html
<a href="/events/index/?id=2" target="_blank" class="bt" data-id="2">Смотреть</a>
<br>
<button onclick="getId();">id</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все `data`-атрибуты хранятся в свойстве [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) элемента. Получить значение поможет `element.dataset.id` или же `element.dataset["id"]`.